# Regex Mobile Number Validation Code Doesn't Work In PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation

```
    function PricerrTheme_isValidNumber($number)
{
    return eregi("^(?:01)?01[0-9]\d{8}$", $number);
}
```

Hello, i would like to add a validation code that validates mobile numbers with the following area codes

```
0100,0101,0106,0109
```

then 7 digits after that so it looks like this

> 01005555555 or 01015555555

my code doesn't work, it always gives me the validation error it doesn't matter if i entered the right or the wrong values

Comment: step #1: dump ereg. it's obsolete and deprecated. using the preg_*() functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you further.

```
 $phone = "01005555555";

   if(preg_match("/^010[0|1|6|9][0-9]{7}$/", $phone)) {
   echo "valid";
   }
   else { 
   echo "invalid";
   }
```

Comment: Why the '{4}' unless you have 4 arrea code in your hpone number... this and the last '|' will let you put an empty value

Comment: should be "/^010[0169][0-9]{7}$/"

Answer (score 0):

**php  code:**

```
$re = "/^010[0169]{1}\\d{7}$/";
$str = "01005555555";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

[regex live demo](http://regex101.com/r/aE3pF2/1)

easier php:

```
 function PricerrTheme_isValidNumber($number)
{
    return  preg_match("/^010[0169]{1}\\d{7}$/", $number);
}
```

html:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^010[0169]{1}\d{7}$" />
```